# Deconstruct a Promise with the expected value when it can throw an Error Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a code that looks like this

```
interface A {
  properties: object
}

const asyncFunction = async (): Promise<A | Error> => {
  try {
    return await anotherAsyncFunction();
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
}
```

Then I want to deconstruct

```
const { properties = {}} = await asyncFunction();
```

But since `asyncFunction` can return either an `A` or an `Error` TS shows

> Property 'properties' does not exist on type 'Error | A'.

Is there a way to handle the Promise with multiple Types and the deconstruction?

Comment: `Promise<A | Error>` is seems wrong - a rejection does not result in the promise resolving with `Error`.

Comment: `throw`ing an error is not the same as `return`ing an error.  Why not just `Promise<A>`? What breaks if you do that?

Comment: Thanks @VLAZ your comment lead me to fix the code.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz your comment lead me to fix the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider removing the `| Error` from the `Promise` typing. Normally, the error path should be a rejection.  In that case your destructuring code would work fine.

If you require to pass an `Error` back in a success path then you will need to use a type guard to determine if your `Promise` success value is `A` or `Error`.

```
function isA(result: A | Error): result is A {
    return (<A>result)?.properties;
}

const result = await asyncFunction();
if (isA(result)) {
   const { properties } = result;
} else {
   const error = result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @timmcb, as you stated, I have to remove the `| Error`. However, if I was returning an error, I would consider using the function